# How to solve portable jndi name problem in unit tests?

Tags: glassfish-embedded

I am using javaee6/ejb3.1 api with glassfish embedded server.
my application structure is ui-controller module ejbs calls biz-controller ejbs.
with the global jndi name format is java:global/myapp/mymodule/myejb.

But when I try to unit test both modules without packaging application on embedded server; get different application name for jndi which is related to temp folder ...

Please find the console log here..

The jndi names generated are like..
`java:global/ejb-app1138741107347091524/controllers/ArticleService`
every time I run the test

```
java:global/ejb-appXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/controllers/ArticleService
```

### XXXXXXXX in ejb-app name in jndi name gets changed...

```
    FINE: [Application] -C:-DOCUME~1-daunddig-LOCALS~1-Temp-ejb-app1138741107347091524- , uid: 84898074169442304
Jan 19, 2011 6:26:46 PM com.sun.enterprise.deployment.Application setUniqueId
FINE: Ejb  classes.jar:ArticleFacadeImpl id = 84898074169442304
Jan 19, 2011 6:26:46 PM com.sun.enterprise.deployment.Application setUniqueId
FINE: Ejb  controllers-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT.jar:ArticleService id = 84898074169442305
Jan 19, 2011 6:26:46 PM com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer initializeHome
INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB ArticleFacadeImpl : [java:global/ejb-app1138741107347091524/ui-boundaries/ArticleFacadeImpl!dd.ecb.jee6.fa
cades.ArticleFacade, java:global/ejb-app1138741107347091524/ui-boundaries/ArticleFacadeImpl]
Jan 19, 2011 6:26:46 PM com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer initializeHome
INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB ArticleService : [java:global/ejb-app1138741107347091524/controllers/ArticleService!dd.ecb.jee6.services.i
mpl.ArticleService, java:global/ejb-app1138741107347091524/controllers/ArticleService]
```

Comment: The container is mandated to map the bean to 

java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>
Where
<aplication-name> defaults to the bundle name (.ear file name) without the bundle extension. This can be overridden in application.xml. Also, <application-name> is applicable only if the bean is packaged inside a .ear file.
Here my application is not bundled in a jar and i am doing unit testing from maven and eclipse. the application name is the generated temporary folder name

Answer (score 1):

solved the issue by configuring applciation name at the time of creating ejb container in javase code...

```
 prop.put(javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "ecb-app");       
 facade = (ArticleFacade)EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(prop).getContext().lookup("java:global/ecb-app/ui-boundaries/ArticleFacadeImpl");
```